# Rapid tap doesn't fire touchesEnded

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Ok, so I am hoping someone can shed some light on this. The thing is I have an app where the user can interact with a number of "pads" that are kind of like big icons, that can be dragged around on the screen. Tapping once on the pad opens it and tapping and holding brings up an alert view which asks if you want to delete it. I am using a timer to check that a user is tapping and holding and invalidating the timer in the touchesMoved and touchesEnded events. The thing is that if you tap very quickly on a pad the touchesEnded event is never fired and as such the delete dialog appears, which can get a little confusing for a user. Any thoughts on why this is?

```
- (void) startTouchTimer:(float)delay 
{
    self.touchTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:delay target:self selector:@selector(touchHeld:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}


- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    if (touches.count == 1) 
    {
        for(WishPad *pad in self.view.subviews) 
        {
            if ([touch view] == pad)
            {
                //Animate Selection
                [UIView animateWithDuration:0.03
                                  delay:0 
                                options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState 
                             animations:^{
                                 pad.highlight.alpha = 0.5;
                             } 
                             completion:NULL];

                self.touchedPad = pad.padName;
                [self startTouchTimer:0.40];
                [self.view bringSubviewToFront:pad];
             }
         }
    }
}


- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    [self.touchTimer invalidate];
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    if (touches.count == 1) 
    {
        for(WishPad *pad in self.view.subviews) 
        {
            if ([touch view] == pad)
            {
                CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
                pad.center =location;       
            }
        }
    }
}


- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event 
{
    [self.touchTimer invalidate];
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    if (touches.count == 1) 
    {
        for(WishPad *pad in self.view.subviews) 
        {
            if ([touch view] == pad)
            {
                //Animate deselection
                [UIView animateWithDuration:0.03
                                  delay:0 
                                options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState 
                             animations:^{
                                 pad.highlight.alpha = 0;
                             } 
                             completion:NULL];

                CGPoint location = pad.frame.origin; 
                NSString *position = NSStringFromCGPoint(location);
                iWishAppDelegate *delegate = (iWishAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

                for (Wish in [delegate.wishes objectForKey:@"<none>"]) 
                {
                   if ([position isEqual:Wish.position] && [[(WishPad*)[touch view] padName] isEqualToString:Wish.name]) 
                    {
                        self.goToAddWish = [[AddWish alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddWish" bundle:nil];
                        self.goToAddWish.editWish=YES;
                        self.goToAddWish.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed=YES;
                        [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.goToAddWish animated:YES];
                        [self.goToAddWish editDetailText:Wish];
                        [self.goToAddWish release];
                    }

                    else if ([pad.padName isEqual:Wish.name]) 
                    {
                        Wish.position = position;
                        [delegate save];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


- (void) touchHeld:(NSTimer*)timer 
{
    [self.touchTimer invalidate];
    NSString *wishToDel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Delete %@?", self.touchedPad];
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:wishToDel message:@"Do you really want to delete this wish?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Delete", nil];
    [alertView show];
    [alertView release];
}


- (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex 
{

    if (buttonIndex == [alertView cancelButtonIndex]) 
    {
            //Lots of deleting from plist and deleting image stuff happening here
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `UIGestureRecognizer`s instead.

You would have to set up the gesture recognizer for all your pads

```
for(WishPad *pad in self.view.subviews) 
{
  UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(padTapped:)];
  [pad addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
  [tapRecognizer release];

  UILongPressGestureRecognizer *pressRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(padPressed:)];
  [pad addGestureRecognizer:pressRecognizer];
  [pressRecognizer release];

}
```

and the you can handle the taps and presses

```
- (void)padTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
  WishPad *pad = (WishPad *)recognizer.view;
  // handle tap for pad
}

- (void)padPressed:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
  WishPad *pad = (WishPad *)recognizer.view;
  // handle long press for pad
}
```

You can control how long a press should take to be recognized as a press using `minimumPressDuration`. But just read up on [UIGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html). It can save you a ton of work.

Comment: Ok, so I tried adding UIGestureRecognizers and it works great, with one exception. That is, when I touch a pad I want it to go slightly dark, to signify that it's being acted upon. The problem right now is that I can get this effect to work on UILongPressGestureRecognizer and UIPanGestureRecognizer but not on  UITapGestureRecognizer. Actually, what I want is for the pad to go dark whenever you touch it, regardless of what you do...is that possible, without using touchesBegan which is what was causing my problems to begin with?